# std::shared_ptr<T>: implicit constructor for rvalue pointer to T

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, rvalue

I pretty much support the idea of making `std::shared_ptr<T>` constructor that accepts `T *` explicit. it helps to save sleepless night, when you are looking the reason on heap corruption. *Scott Meyers* gave a good explanation for this.

---

But... If I give it an `rvalue` pointer isn't this explicit? I could do things like:

```
/// (1)
std::shared_ptr<T> t = new T;
```

or

```
/// (2)
T * giveaway = new T;
std::shared_ptr<T> t = std::move(giveaway);
```

or a much more painful case from real life

```
/// (3)
void foo(std::shared_ptr<T> t);
/// ...
foo(new T);
```

---

As for me, all these cases are explicit enough.

Case (1) is a `prvalue`, I can't possibly screw myself up having two pointers. At least no more than using:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> t{new T};
```

Case (2) is pretty much explicit. It is agreed that after you have moved something its value becomes undefined. So using it is totally on you.

Case (3) is an `rvalue` again.

---

**(Q1)** It this is an overlook by standard committee?

**(Q2)** Is there a reason for this?

**(Q3)** Any chance for implicit constructor accepting `rvalue` to appear in C++14?

Comment: To Q3: C++14 is official, and that did not change.

Comment: Did I miss something? Why not using make_shared?

Comment: @MarcoA. Same reason we not use `std::string("literal")` everywhere where we pass literal to function that accepts `std::string`. It's simplicity.

Comment: okay, although it might stand for case 2, but case 1 and 3 are actually more performant and safer with make_shared

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a reason even giving an rvalue does not allow implicit construction of a smart-pointer from a raw-pointer:

**It is not safe.**

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<T> t);
char buffer[42];
foo(buffer+7); // buffer+7 is a rvalue, and would implicitly convert!
```

Thus, to the other two parts of your question:

1. It is not an oversight by the committee.

And

3. It will not appear in a future C++-standard (Anyway, C++14 is out and it *did not* appear).